# Choosing an origin in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Assume that $n>1$, and that $\{p_j\}$ is a discrete sequence in $\mathbb{C}^n$ (without repetition). Is it possible to find an origin of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $0 < |p_1| < |p_2| < \dots$?

The answer is yes and it is used in [a paper by Rosay and Rudin](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-310-01/S0002-9947-1988-0929658-4/S0002-9947-1988-0929658-4.pdf).

Comment: They omitted the remark that the sequence $(p_k)$ may have to be reordered. The point is the existence of some $z\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\lvert p_k - z\rvert \neq \lvert p_m - z\rvert$ whenever $k\neq m$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I realize that now. Spencer constructed a nice counterexample in his answer. If rearrangement is allowed then the problem boils down to finding a point in $\mathbb{C}^n$ which is not equidistant to any 2 points in the sequence and that can be done by induction.

Comment: Better to use that the set of points having equal distance to two of the $p_k$ is a null set  (a countable union of hyperplanes).

Comment: Yes, that will also work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Consider the sequence in $\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $(1,0)$, $(0,0)$, $(3,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(5,0)$, $(4,0)$, ...

If $q=(x_1+iy_1,x_2+iy_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ and $|p_k-q|<|p_{k+1}-q|$ for all $k$, then
$$|q-(2n+1,0)|^2<|q-(2n,0)|^2$$
for all $n$. This means that
$$(x_1-2n-1)^2+y_1^2+x_2^2+y_2^2<(x_1-2n)^2+y_1^2+x_2^2+y_2^2,$$
which simplifies to
$$-2x_1+4n+1<0.$$
But this cannot hold for all $n$.